# PhoneGap image from external source

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

I have strange problem when I try to display image in my PhoneGap app with some external source, app works fine in browser but when I open it on a mobile phone for example in PhoneGap Developer image doesn't render.

```
<li>
  <a href="#">
   <img src="http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/80-90/shopping/pixs/4585/c/Cu_11515095._cute-basket-of-fresh-pink-roses-flower-gift-282.jpg" width="80" height="80">
   <h3>8.3.2016</h3>
   </a>
</li>
```

[How image is rendered in PhoneGap Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Js4h.png)

I even added following lines into my config.xml but nothing has changed:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Something still blocking external resources...

Comment: is your `index.html` have content security policy ?